# How to speed up this simple query

Tags: sql, sql-server

With `SourceTable` having > 15MM records and `Bad_Phrase` having > 3K records, the following query takes almost 10 hours to run on SQL Server 2005 SP4.

```
Update [SourceTable] 
Set Bad_Count = (Select count(*) 
                 from Bad_Phrase 
                 where [SourceTable].Name like '%'+Bad_Phrase.PHRASE+'%')
```

In English, this query is counting the number of times that any phrases listed in `Bad_Phrase` are a substring of the column `[Name]` in the `SourceTable` and then placing that result in the column `Bad_Count`.

I would like some suggestions on how to have this query run considerably faster.

Comment: Best thing is to look at the execution plan - likely there are some clues there.... is this MSSQL?

Comment: i dont think it possible unless you can change `Name like '%'+Bad_Phrase.PHRASE+'%'` to `Name like Bad_Phrase.PHRASE+'%'`. if you could do that, then you could create an index for the Name column and it would run much faster. basically the way you use `LIKE` prevents indexing from being used and  therefore the count can't be made faster (afaik)

Comment: You know, you're actually counting the number of distinct bad phrases that occur in the Name field - multiple occurrences of the same phrase won't be counted.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yeah but he said make it faster not slower :D

Comment: @Charleh hey [if it doesn't have to be correct..](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2009/09/29/i-can-make-it-arbitrarily-fast-if-i-don-t-actually-have-to-make-it-work.aspx)

Comment: A full text index might help

Comment: Some strategies I would research if confronted with this problem. 1) Maybe it is time to learn about full text search and see if that is applicable. 2) Save `sourcetable.name` in a decomposed form that allows searches that are sargeable and can use indexes. 3) What is the structure of bad_phrase, and we get close enough with a much smaller set? For example if "__ you" and "__ your dog" maybe just search for "___".

Answer (score 1):

For a lack of a better idea, here is one:

I don't know if SQL Server natively supports parallelizing an `UPDATE` statement, but you can try to do it yourself manually by partitioning the work that needs to be done.

For instance, just as an example, if you can run the following 2 `update` statements in parallel manually or by writing a small app, I'd be curious to see if you can bring down your total processing time.

```
Update [SourceTable] 
Set Bad_Count=(
    Select count(*) 
    from Bad_Phrase 
    where [SourceTable].Name like '%'+Bad_Phrase.PHRASE+'%'
)
where Name < 'm'

Update [SourceTable] 
Set Bad_Count=(
    Select count(*) 
    from Bad_Phrase 
    where [SourceTable].Name like '%'+Bad_Phrase.PHRASE+'%'
)
where Name >= 'm'
```

So the 1st `update` statement takes care of updating all the rows whose names start with the letters `a-l`, and the 2nd query takes care of `o-z`.

It's just an idea, and you can try splitting this into smaller chunks and more parallel `update` statements, depending on the capacity of your SQL Server machine.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your query is scanning the whole table.  Does your tables have proper indexes on them.  Putting an index on columns that appear in a where clause is a good place to start.  You can also try and get the cost of the query in the Sql server management studio (display estimated execution cost) or if your willing to wait (display actual execution cost) are both buttons in the query window.  The cost will provide insights as to what is taking forever and possibly steer you to wright faster queries.

Comment: If you're searching using `like '%.....%`, no index will ever be able to help you ...

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the table using sub query with the same table, every row update will scan the whole table and that may cause too much execution time. I think is better if you will insert first all data in the `#temp` table and then use the `#temp` table in your update statement. Or you can `JOIN` the Source table and Temp table as well.